# Loading input from a file in lex

Tags: command-line, input

First of all, I was not sure whether to post this question here or on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com), but here's my question anyway.

Besides using `input redirection`, i.e. `./code < inputFile.dat`, is there any way I can load my data file into a program written in  `lex`?

Basically, here's how I would like to be able to load my data: `./code inputFile.dat`

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: lex as in the lexical analyser generator?

Comment: yes, sir. I am referring to the lexical analyser `lex` under Linux

Comment: Under Linux you won't find lex, that one is propietary (and quite bit-rotted by now AFAIU). You are using flex, which is quite different. And its manual (the info version) should be more than enough to show you how it is done.

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/lex` symlink to flex.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would use

```
%%
main() { yylex(); }
```

which reads the input from stdin.

To make read it from a file

```
%%
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fh;

    if (argc == 2 && (fh = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
        yyin = fh;
    yylex();
    return 0;
}
```

Source  O'Reilly's `lex & yacc`.